# C program with 10 options

Tags: c

I have a C program where the user can select from 10 different options. I've already split the core functionality of each option into different methods, but my `main()` function is still quite long. The rest of the code in `main()` involves getting user input and formatting strings to the display so that the program is clearer and looks nice.

E.g. my code is similar to:

```
int actionOneFunction(char *name) {
    /* Action one logic */
}

int actionTwoFunction(FILE *fptr) {
    /* Action two logic */
}

void getUserInput(char *display_msg, char *input_variable, int variable_size) {
    printf("%s", display_msg);
    fgets(input_variable, variable_size, stdin);
    strtok(input_variable, "\n"); /* Remove newline added by fgets */
}

void displayStartingText() {
    /* 
        A bunch of printf statements
    */
}

int main() {
    int result
    int action;

    displayStartingText();

    printf("Select the action you would like to carry out: ");
    scanf("%d", &action);
    getChar(); /* Remove newline generated by scanf from buffer */

    if (action < 0 || action > 10) {
        printf("Invalid action selected.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (action == 1) {
        char name[255];
        
        printf("------------\n");
        printf(" Action One \n");
        printf("------------\n");

        getUserInput("Enter the name: ", name, sizeof(name));
        result = actionOneFunction(name);
        if (result != 0) {
            return errno;
        }
        printf("Action one was successful!\n");
    }
    else if (action == 2) {
        FILE *fptr;
        char name[255];
        char *content;

        printf("------------\n");
        printf(" Action Two \n");
        printf("------------\n");

        getUserInput("Enter the file name: ", name, sizeof(name));

        fptr = openFile(name, "r");
        content = actionTwoFunction(fptr);
        fclose(fptr);

        printf("Content: \n", content);
    }
    else if (action == 3) {
        /* ... */
    }

    /* 
        ... 
    */

    else if (action == 10) {
        /* ... */
    }

    return 0;

}
```

With all ten options and their functionality defined, my `main()` becomes rather long. Would it be better to put each of the `if` blocks into their own functions?

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: @TobySpeight My apologies. I was directed to CodeReview as the best place to ask about code formatting or stylistic questions, which is exactly my question here. Is there a better place on StackExchange to ask about this?

Comment: It seems you were badly advised - you should have been pointed at our [help] before you asked.  I think you should delete this question, then you have two options: if you're in a position to post some real code here, then create a new question using that; otherwise you might look to see if [softwareengineering.se] is appropriate (look at what is [on-topic](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there).

Comment: @TobySpeight I see. I, unfortunately, cannot delete the question due to the existence of an answer.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Not a problem - the community will likely close it.  I hope the rest of my advice is more useful!

Comment: Definitely so! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be very detailed here because I haven't worked in C lately. But basically, yes, you should move more of the code out of the `if` statements into the breakout functions.

Specifically, each break-out function should have the same signature (type/arity). Based on the examples you've given so far, these appear to be quite open-ended effectful subroutines, each comparable to a mini `main`, so they might as well have signature `()->int`. Or maybe there'll be enough structure to their behavior that you can be more specific than that, IDK.

If you're going to print out the fancy headers, abstract that away into a helper function.

Anyway, you might consider even getting rid of the `if` itself, in favor of a lookup-table *of functions*. Exactly how to implement that will depend a bit on the context; it's not something I've ever done in C.

Comment: My current breakout functions already perform their own specialized tasks, so I want to avoid adding *anything* to them, if possible. Would it be fine to create new breakout functions for each `if` block that call the other specialized functions?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe you could even parameterize the wrapper in some way; it's hard to say without a sense of the space of functionality that's already included or might want to be added later.